# How can I call scalar functions in a table view based on conditions?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a sample view defined as;

```
 CREATE view [ab].[udv_SUMMARY] as 
select 
  txt.[Timestamp],   
 txt.[Site], 
   txt.[Name],  
  txt.[Variance]
 from [ab].Text_Table txt
```

I have 3 user defined functions( [udf_BJ_CT],[udf_BJ_MD],[udf_BJ_NY]

I need to change **Variance** value based on the output of all those 3 functions.

- How can I call these 3 functions in the view based on the **Site** parameter?
  Note: My functions take parameters as **timestamp and Site**.

Comment: I need to change Variance value based on the output of all those 3 functions. - How?

Comment: you can call the function 
select 
 ...,
 dbo.udf_BJ_CT(txt.[Timestamp],txt.[Site])
from [ab].Text_Table txt

Comment: @AbdulRasheed i have defined 3 functions, I want to call them based on the condition Site parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CASE WHEN` here.

```
CREATE view [ab].[udv_SUMMARY] as 
select 
    txt.[Timestamp],   
    txt.[Site], 
    txt.[Name],  
    txt.[Variance],
    (CASE   WHEN txt.[Site] = {CONDITION 1} THEN dbo.[udf_BJ_CT](txt.[Timestamp],txt.[Site])
            WHEN txt.[Site] = {CONDITION 2} THEN dbo.[udf_BJ_MD](txt.[Timestamp],txt.[Site])
            WHEN txt.[Site] = {CONDITION 3} THEN dbo.[udf_BJ_NY](txt.[Timestamp],txt.[Site])
            ELSE dbo.[Def_Fxn](...)
    END)
 from [ab].Text_Table txt
```

You have to replace your actual condition with `{CONDITION 1},{CONDITION 2} and {CONDITION 3}`

Comment: Thanks , One more quick question. I have a default function too to be called. How can I add that in the when condition. (Means, if there is other Site occur, I have to call the default function)

Comment: use ELSE here, ie CASE WHEN .... WHEN ... ELSE dbo.def_fxn() END. Please check the modified answer..